# Which event is called on clicking "Hide" in stop sharing panel?

Tags: javascript

I want to hide the stop sharing panel in the background by default. But I didn't get which event is called on clicking the "hide".
I have implemented screeen sharing using JS API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If i got your question, first get the id of the `hide` by inspecting the element.
Then;

```
window.onload(() => {
    document.getElementById('id_of_hide').click();
});
```

This will automatically click the `hide` after the window loads thus it will be hidden after window loads.

Comment: I could not find the id of this because this is kind of panel which exists separately to the page.
I am adding the screen-shot to make you understand.